# How to run independent instances of gtest for two separate linux processes (one for client and one for server)?

Tags: linux, cmake, googletest

I have two separate linux processes: One for client and one for server. They share some common code and libraries but their application code is independent of each other.

**Goal:** Run an independent set of test cases on the client and on the server simultaneously. The desire is to trigger the server in a specific minimal way while the client related tests are in progress. (Mocking/ stubbing would be too cumbersome in this case).
Here's the excerpt from **`CMakefiles.txt`:**

```
target_link_libraries(Client SHARED FILES_GLOB src/client/* FILES_GLOB src/common/*
    DEPENDS common_libaries)
target_link_libraries(Client PRIVATE gtest)
target_link_libraries(Server SHARED FILES_GLOB src/server/* FILES_GLOB src/common/*
    DEPENDS common_libaries)
target_link_libraries(Server PRIVATE gtest)
```

I have a separate set of test cases for client and for server in their respective folders:

```
TEST_F(serverTest#1) ... TEST_F(serverTest#n)
TEST_F(clientTest#1) ... TEST_F(clientTest#n)
```

As a starting point (to make things simpler), `InitGoogleTest()` is run-time disabled on the server based on a config parameter. The code is something like this:

> server/app.cpp:

```
if (gtestMode) { // == false
   ::testing::InitGoogleTest();
   ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "*abcd*";
   RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

On the client side, InitGoogleTest() etc. are run-time enabled and do get invoked.

However, when I launch the two applications/ processes back to back from the command-line, the test cases defined on the ***server side*** are being invoked. Here's the sample output:

```
[==========] Running 122 tests from 5 test suites. *(I have 5 test suites on the server side. Not on the client. I've added one test suite on the client just now)*
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from TestFixture *(This is a server based test fixture name)*
[ RUN      ] TestFixture.ServerTest1
  Feature: link Setup
...
```

Questions:

1. How come the gtest library on the client side (linked PRIVATEly) is even able to see the test fixtures on the server side? They are in different processes.
2. What is the correct way to make the gtest on the client independent of the gtest on the server?

Please let me know if you need further information about this. As always, any insights you can offer would be of great value.

Regards,
Venk